# JQuery code is not working. What am I doing wrong? Callbacks, variable scope, chaining?

Tags: jquery

Basically, I have HTML5 markup with two empty divs. I want to use JQuery to populate those divs with two separate forms and 2 separate flash messages based on whether a single localStorage value exists. As I've been building it, it's been working up until the point I wrote the code for dynamically displaying a form. Can someone toy with this code and tell me what I'm missing? I'm not a JavaScript expert (but I'd like to be) - I'm stuck on a rut here. Edit: So far, fixed the issue of forms not displaying. But the flash messages do not appear either, and when a button is pressed, it doesn't store the value in localStorage anymore, it makes the form disappear and then fade back in again. :(

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Shrink Once API Tools</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css"></link>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <h1 class="head-title">Shrink Once API Tools</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div id="flashAlert">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="mainFormContent">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Include JavaScript at the very bottom for faster page loads -->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--
    Fall back on local JQuery if Google CDN version is unavailable.
    (Since most sites link the Google CDN version, it is more likely
    to already be cached by the user's browser).
    -->
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/vendor/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
    <!-- end Fallback -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            var apiKeyForm = '<form>'
                           + '<legend>Enter your API Key</legend>'
                           + '<input type="text" id="apiKey" class="span12" placeholder="e.g. ab12c34d5678efgh90123i45678j90k1">'
                           + '<span class="help-block">You can find your access key <a href="https://shrinkonce.com/index.php?menu=usercp#tools" target="blank">here.</a></span>'
                           + '<button type="submit" id="saveAPIKey" class="btn btn-info btn-large btn-block">Save</button>'
                           + '</form>';

            var apiLinkForm = '<form>'
                            + '<legend>Add a link or two... or more.</legend>'
                            + '<button id="add" class="btn btn-large">Add</button>'
                            + '<button id="remove" class="btn btn-large">Remove</button>'
                            + '<button id="reset" class="btn btn-large">Reset</button>'
                            + '<button type="submit" class="btn btn-info btn-large">Submit</button>'
                            + '<hr />'
                            + '<div id="linkForm">'
                            + '</div>'
                            + '</form>';

            var i = $('#linkForm input').size() + 1;
            $('#add').click(function () {
                $('<input type="text" id="inputLink' + i + '" class="shrinklink span12" placeholder="http://google.com">').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('#linkForm');
                i++;
                return false;
            });
            $('#remove').click(function () {
                if (i > 1) {
                    $('.shrinklink:last').fadeOut('normal', function () { $(this).remove(); });
                    i--;
                }
                return false;
            });
            $('#reset').click(function () {
                while (i > 2) {
                    $('.shrinklink:last').remove();
                    i--;
                }
                return false;
            });
            $("#saveAPIKey").click(function () {
                if (typeof $('#apiKey').val() !== null) {
                    localStorage.setItem(apiKey, $('#apiKey').val());
                    $(apiKeyForm).fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.mainFormContent');
                }
                else {
                    alert("API Key not set!");
                }
                return false;
            });

            if (localStorage.length > 0) {
                $('<div class="alert alert-error">You have not yet entered your API token. Add it below, and it will be persisted in memory.</div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.flashAlert');
                $(apiLinkForm).fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.mainFormContent');
            }
            else {
                $('<div class="alert alert-success">Your API token is ' + localStorage.getItem(apiKey) + '.</div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.flashAlert');
                $(apiKeyForm).fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.mainFormContent');
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Didn't see anywhere that `apiKeyForm` abd `apiLinkForm` to be attached to the DOM.

Comment: That's in the very last part of the code, lines 4-11 from the bottom.

Comment: Yes, but it never happened because `apiKey` is not defined

Comment: Are you sure? Before I added the check for localStorage, I had an alert() that would alert the apiKey localStorage key and it worked just fine, it displayed the value the user entered when the save button was pressed. Forgive me for sounding blunt (I'm not trying to be) but apiKey worked fine before...

Comment: as I answered below you may be meen `localStorage.getItem('apiKey')` insted of `localStorage.getItem(apiKey)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

not sure but maybe it should be `localStorage.getItem('apiKey')`

Comment: Well, that fixed the issue of the form not displaying, but the flash message still continues to evade me.

Comment: You should initialize your click handlers after appending the nodes to the DOM and should do first `.appendTo` and just after that `.fadeIn`

Comment: For example: `$(apiLinkForm).fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.mainFormContent');` should be `$(apiLinkForm).appendTo('.mainFormContent').fadeIn('slow');` and at least half of the functionality will work. And If you think this answer was useful for you you could vote it up.

Comment: How does one initialize a click handler? And I'll get on that last part, see if it makes a difference

Comment: first change the order of `.fadeIn` and `.appendTo`

Comment: `$('#add').click(function () {
                $('<input type="text" id="inputLink' + i + '" class="shrinklink span12" placeholder="http://google.com">').appendTo('#linkForm').fadeIn('slow');
                i++;
                return false;
            });
` should be moved down because you add `#add` button in the last  lines of you code and currently the `$('#add')` is not initialized yet when trying to attach a click handler to it

Comment: Moving everything helped a great deal, and seeing results cleared my head a little - I missed that I was selecting Div ID's rather than classes for the flash messages. Derp moment for the lose :$ - moving the .fade() to the end negated the fade effect though. Now I have two problems; 1. when hitting the "save" button, the apiKeyForm is just added again underneath the original. Once that's solved, I can move on to problem 2: automatically changing the form to the apiLinkForm when the save button is pressed. I'm sure I can figure these out on my own, though. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined the variable called "apiKey" anywhere, this is throwing a js error on the following line.

```
$('<div class="alert alert-success">Your API token is ' + localStorage.getItem(apiKey) + '.</div>').fadeIn('slow').appendTo('.flashAlert');
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/aLF6p/

Comment: It isn't a variable value per se, it is a localStorage key declared in this line: localStorage.setItem(apiKey, $('#apiKey').val());

Comment: the first param of setItem is a string, and your code is throwing a js Error becuase you are trying to access an undefined variable.